# Installing Raspberry Pi OS through laptop by ssh

Tags: ssh, software-installation

I just got a Raspberry Pi B and I got not any keyboard or HDMI cable at reach. I wonder if I can actually load an OS (like Arch Linux for Raspberry) and once it's plugged by Ethernet to my home network connect by ssh and perform the whole first use and settings from there.

I wonder it's possible based on this [link](http://elinux.org/RPi_Remote_Access).

Comment: Last time I checked, SSH wasn't enabled on a fresh install of Raspbian. If you have a linux PC, you could just edit the filesystem on the sd-card to (temporarily) enable ssh. Something like adding `/etc/init.d/ssh start` to the file `/etc/rc.local`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've flashed an OS onto the SD card, you should be able to plug it in, and ssh into the Pi.

You will need the IP address of the Pi to SSH into it, but there are a myriad of ways to find the IP address.
A few ways are -

- Checking your routers DHCP lease page
- Using an app called Fing on your Android/iPhone to do a local network scan (assuming your 
  network as wifi)
- Doing a ping scan from another PC on the network.

Comment: I got the Pi's ip in my home network, I tried to do a:

`ssh root@192.168.0.10` and
`ssh root@192.168.0.10 -X`

And I only got a connection timeout

Comment: @Diego have you copied the proper OS (Raspbian) image to your SD card? does it boot? do the LED light flash intermittently? if both answers are 'yes', you should use name/pass "pi"/"raspberry" because these are Raspbian defaults. there's no "root" login in Raspbian

Comment: I got LED's flashing but I copied Arch Linux for Raspberry, I'll try out with Raspbian

Comment: @Diego ssh daemon might be disabled by default in Arch, sorry, I have only Raspbian experience.

Comment: Thanks, it's OK. So it's actually possible to only load the OS in the SD and install Raspbian from there by ssh, right?

Comment: Generally, when you load the OS into the SD card, that *is* installing the OS.